# Border no funciona de la forma esperada cuando se modifica la tabla con javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Estoy haciendo una pequeña página que dependiendo del dato que reciba (a través de `websockets`) muestra una `tabla` u otra. Mi idea es que cuando llega el dato para una u otra `tabla` la otra se oculta con el `método` `display none` y la otra se muestra con el `método` `display block` y como sólo se modifica el cuerpo, predefino el resto de los elementos de la tabla, entre ellos el `border`.

Cuando apenas se carga la página aparecen las dos `tablas` (dado que todavía no se recibió dato alguno) y en cuanto llega un nuevo "mensaje" se fuerza a que una `tabla` se muestre y la otra no, pero esta vez con los datos. Cuando se dibuja por primera vez el `borde` dibujado de la `tabla` ocupa la menor dimensión posible, pero cuando llega un dato el `borde` de la `tabla` ocupa toda la pantalla y los `bordes` de los `td` se ajustan a los datos que contienen. ¿Qué puede estar pasando?

Edición 1: Dejo captura de pantalla de lo que pasa: http://prntscr.com/ofajfg

Dejo el código aunque en el no se pueda ver el error (hace falta que le lleguen los datos por `websocket`).

```js
var connection = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:algún_puerto/ws/pruebaWebsocket', ['soap', 'xmpp']);
var datos = {};
// When the connection is open, send some data to the server
connection.onopen = function () {
  connection.send('Ping'); // Send the message 'Ping' to the server
};

// Log errors
connection.onerror = function (error) {
  console.log('WebSocket Error ' + error);
};

// Log messages from the server
connection.onmessage = function (e) {
  var temp = JSON.parse(e.data);
  if(temp.topic === "reloj")
  {
    document.getElementById("asd").innerHTML = Date(datos.payload).toString();
  }
  else if(temp.topic === "piezasTotales")
  {
    console.log(temp);
  }
  else if(temp.topic === "ops1")
  {
    document.getElementById("selectorOp").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("informe").style.display = "none";
    datos = temp;
    llenarTabla1();
  }
  else
  {
    document.getElementById("selectorOp").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("informe").style.display = "block";
    datos = temp;
    llenarTabla();
  }
};

function enviar()
{
  connection.send("prueba");
}

function llenarTabla()
{
  console.log(datos);
  var abiertas = 0;
  var completadas = 0;
  var tbodie = document.getElementById("tbodie");
  for(var i = 0; i < datos.payload.length; i++) {
    var trCuerpo = document.createElement("tr");
    var td1 = document.createElement("td");
    var td2 = document.createElement("td");
    var td3 = document.createElement("td");
    var td4 = document.createElement("td");
    var td5 = document.createElement("td");
    var td6 = document.createElement("td");
    var td7 = document.createElement("td");
    var td8 = document.createElement("td");
    var td9 = document.createElement("td");
    var td10 = document.createElement("td");
    var td11 = document.createElement("td");
    var td12 = document.createElement("td");
    var td13 = document.createElement("td");
    var td14 = document.createElement("td");
    var td15 = document.createElement("td");
    var td16 = document.createElement("td");
    var td17 = document.createElement("td");
    var td18 = document.createElement("td");
    var td19 = document.createElement("td");
    var td20 = document.createElement("td");
    var td21 = document.createElement("td");
    var td22 = document.createElement("td");

    td1.appendChild(document.createTextNode(datos.payload[i].op));
    td2.appendChild(document.createTextNode(datos.payload[i].total));
    td3.appendChild(document.createTextNode(datos.payload[i].reprocesos.mel));
    td4.appendChild(document.createTextNode(datos.payload[i].reprocesos.pvc));
    td5.appendChild(document.createTextNode(datos.payload[i].reprocesos.vid));
    td6.appendChild(document.createTextNode(datos.payload[i].reprocesos.otr));
    td7.appendChild(document.createTextNode(datos.payload[i].frentes.mel));
    td8.appendChild(document.createTextNode(datos.payload[i].frentes.pvc));
    td9.appendChild(document.createTextNode(datos.payload[i].frentes.vid));
    td10.appendChild(document.createTextNode(datos.payload[i].frentes.otr));
    td11.appendChild(document.createTextNode(datos.payload[i].frenRep.mel));
    td12.appendChild(document.createTextNode(datos.payload[i].frenRep.pvc));
    td13.appendChild(document.createTextNode(datos.payload[i].frenRep.vid));
    td14.appendChild(document.createTextNode(datos.payload[i].frenRep.otr));
    td15.appendChild(document.createTextNode(datos.payload[i].piezas.mel));
    td16.appendChild(document.createTextNode(datos.payload[i].piezas.pvc));
    td17.appendChild(document.createTextNode(datos.payload[i].piezas.vid));
    td18.appendChild(document.createTextNode(datos.payload[i].piezas.otr));
    td19.appendChild(document.createTextNode(datos.payload[i].pieRep.mel));
    td20.appendChild(document.createTextNode(datos.payload[i].pieRep.pvc));
    td21.appendChild(document.createTextNode(datos.payload[i].pieRep.vid));
    td22.appendChild(document.createTextNode(datos.payload[i].pieRep.otr));

    trCuerpo.appendChild(td1);
    trCuerpo.appendChild(td2);
    trCuerpo.appendChild(td3);
    trCuerpo.appendChild(td4);
    trCuerpo.appendChild(td5);
    trCuerpo.appendChild(td6);
    trCuerpo.appendChild(td7);
    trCuerpo.appendChild(td8);
    trCuerpo.appendChild(td9);
    trCuerpo.appendChild(td10);
    trCuerpo.appendChild(td11);
    trCuerpo.appendChild(td12);
    trCuerpo.appendChild(td13);
    trCuerpo.appendChild(td14);
    trCuerpo.appendChild(td15);
    trCuerpo.appendChild(td16);
    trCuerpo.appendChild(td17);
    trCuerpo.appendChild(td18);
    trCuerpo.appendChild(td19);
    trCuerpo.appendChild(td20);
    trCuerpo.appendChild(td21);
    trCuerpo.appendChild(td22);

    tbodie.appendChild(trCuerpo);

    (datos.payload[i].COMPLETADO===1)?completadas++:abiertas++;
  }
}

function llenarTabla1()
{
  console.log(datos);
  var abiertas = 0;
  var completadas = 0;
  var tbodie = document.getElementById("selectorOpCuerpo");

  for(var i = 0; i < datos.payload.length; i++)
  {
    var trCuerpo = document.createElement("tr");

    var td1 = document.createElement("th");
    var td2 = document.createElement("th");
    var td3 = document.createElement("th");
    var td4 = document.createElement("th");
    td1.appendChild(document.createTextNode(datos.payload[i].ID));
    td2.appendChild(document.createTextNode(datos.payload[i].fecha));
    td3.appendChild(document.createTextNode(datos.payload[i].OP))
    td4.appendChild(document.createTextNode(datos.payload[i].COMPLETADO))

    td1.style.color = (datos.payload[i].COMPLETADO===1)?"green":"red";
    td2.style.color = (datos.payload[i].COMPLETADO===1)?"green":"red";
    td3.style.color = (datos.payload[i].COMPLETADO===1)?"green":"red";
    td4.style.color = (datos.payload[i].COMPLETADO===1)?"green":"red";

    td4.setAttribute('onclick', 'posicion(' + i + ')');

    trCuerpo.appendChild(td1);
    trCuerpo.appendChild(td2);
    trCuerpo.appendChild(td3);
    trCuerpo.appendChild(td4);

    tbodie.appendChild(trCuerpo);

    (datos.payload[i].COMPLETADO===1)?completadas++:abiertas++;
  }

  document.getElementById("cantidad").innerHTML = "<font color=\"green\">completadas: " + completadas + "</font><br><font color=\"red\">abiertas: " + abiertas + "</font>"
}

function posicion(i)
{
  console.log(datos);
  datos.payload[i].COMPLETADO = (datos.payload[i].COMPLETADO===0)?1:0;
  llenarTabla1();
}
```

```html
<div id="asd"></div>
<button onClick="enviar()">enviar</button>
<br>
<div id="cantidad"></div>

<table id="selectorOp" border="1px">
  <thead>
  <tr>
    <th>id</th>
    <th>fecha</th>
    <th>op</th>
    <th>seleccionar</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="selectorOpCuerpo"> </tbody>
</table>

<table id="informe" border="1px">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th rowspan="2">Op</th>
      <th rowspan="2">Total</th>
      <th colspan="4">Total reprocesos</th>
      <th colspan="4">Frentes</th>
      <th colspan="4">Frentes reprocesados</th>
      <th colspan="4">Piezas</th>
      <th colspan="4">Piezas reprocesadas</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>MEL</th>
      <th>MDF</th>
      <th>VID</th>
      <th>otr</th>
      <th>MEL</th>
      <th>MDF</th>
      <th>VID</th>
      <th>otr</th>
      <th>MEL</th>
      <th>MDF</th>
      <th>VID</th>
      <th>otr</th>
      <th>MEL</th>
      <th>MDF</th>
      <th>VID</th>
      <th>otr</th>
      <th>MEL</th>
      <th>MDF</th>
      <th>VID</th>
      <th>otr</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="tbodie"> </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Para mi no es clara tu pregunta, no entendí nada de lo que te pasa con los border

Comment: perdón, por no ser tan claro, pasa que no sé cómo explicarlo. Acá dejo una captura de pantalla: http://prntscr.com/ofajfg

Comment: Colócale a las tablas un width 100%

Comment: Esto sólo hace que la tabla ocupe toda la pantalla, pero cuando llegan los datos simplemente queda igual que en la captura.

Comment: Como tal no creo que el problema sea el borde, creo que lo que pasa es que la longitud de los datos no alcanza a llenar toda la pantalla. El width=100% debería servir o ponle a cada th un width de 25%.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Por defecto, todos las etiquetas tienen ciertas propiedades que los navegadores les aportan. En el caso de las tablas son los siguientes:

> **table**
>
> display: table;
>
> border-collapse: separate;
>
> border-spacing: 2px;
>
> border-color: gray;

Cuando tratas de mostrar la tabla que está oculta, lo que estás haciendo es cambiarle el `display` por uno que va a ocasionar que su comportamiento no sea el esperado.

En vez de usar `display: block` para mostrar la tabla prueba a usar `display: table`, eso debería de solucionarte el problema.

**Referencia:** [Estilos CSS por defecto](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_default_values.asp)

Comment: Eso funcionó perfecto, muchas gracias!